# Asp.Net Core : How to calculate tax and add to the total amount?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I want to add 3% tax to the total amount, but I don't know how to calculate it?

```
int Totalprice = 400000;
double Tax = .03;
int totalpriceWithTax = ?
```

I use This but Not worked

```
  totalpriceWithTax  =  Totalprice + (Totalprice * (Convert.ToInt16(Tax)));
```

Comment: I don't know if there is a more basic thing that u learn in the online examples and to do  not know how to do it ... is send you to basic courses about programing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculations involving currency should **always** be performed with `decimal` precision to avoid floating-point rounding errors. Please see [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) for an explanation of why this is. The code, then, should be:

```
decimal totalPrice = 400000;
decimal tax = 3;
decimal totalpriceWithTax = totalPrice + (totalPrice * (tax / 100));
```

Please also note the changes to the casing of the variable names, camelCase is convention for local variables in C#.